# Infinitive instead of past participle in Maná's "El Verdadero Amor Perdona"

Tags: gramática, participio, infinitivo

In Maná's song "El Verdadero Amor Perdona" one of the verses contains the lines:

> Cómo pude haberte yo herido / engañarte y ofendido

I'd think it should be "Como pude haberte yo herido / engañado y ofendido" (which would fit the song just as well). Why is "engañarte" used instead of "engañado"? Is it proper grammar or stylistic variation for the song?

**Edit:** And if it is stylistic, is there any equivalent or similar usage in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think those lines can be divided like this:

> Cómo pude haberte yo herido
>
> Cómo pude engañarte
>
> Cómo pude haberte yo ofendido

Comment: "How could I have offended you?"

Answer (score 1):

Stylistic.

> Cómo pude haberte yo herido, engañarte y ofendido => Cómo pude haberte yo herido, cómo
> pude engañarte, cómo pude haberte ofendido
>
> Cómo pude haberte yo herido, engañado y ofendido => Cómo pude haberte yo herido, cómo pude
> haberte yo engañado